# Make an inputfield readonly depending on a controller boolean variable

Tags: apex, visualforce, inputfield, read-only

I have an inputfield in an apex page

In my apex class there is a boolean variable depending on which this inputfield should be readonly or readwrite. I have tried using rendered. However that is not serving my purpose as I want the field to be displayed only in readonly format for certain conditions.  I am fairly new to salesforce and any help would be really appreciated

Comment: Please post the code you have tried as well

Answer (score 1):

You can use apex:outputPanel to render the input field.

```
<apex:outputPanel rendered="{!show_read_write}">
     <apex:inputField value="{!value}" />
</apex:outputPanel>
<apex:outputPanel rendered="{!NOT(show_read_write)}">
     <apex:inputField value="{!value}" html-disabled="true"/>
</apex:outputPanel>
```

Comment: I won't be able to use rendered. As it is removing the field altogether. I want the field to be displayed,but, it should be readonly depending on the value.

Comment: The second output Panel will be rendered when the boolean value is false and hence it will display it in read only format.

Comment: I understand and it is probably going to wrong. I just want to know one other thing. Is it possible to do it with any html tag? Is it possible to avoid the rendered attribute?

Comment: Yes you can use html-disabled to disable the inptField

Comment: Yes I tried that but html-disabled is not taking any boolean variable value.

Comment: Updated the code snippet. Do try it. It is working for me.

Answer (score 0):

You Can Use

apex:inputField value="{!Value}" rendered="{!bool}"

Where bool is the boolean variable . On the bases of bool value the field can be shown/hide